# Cascading multi valued parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008

Asssume that there is a report parameter called salesman which is multivalued and is dependent on another report parameter called distributor which is also a multivalued.Each value of distributor is having two salesman values.If i select two distributors i should get 4 related salsman values in the salesman dropdown. how to do it in SSRS 2008 pls help me out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Order the parameters having Distributor first and Salesman second.
2. Set The Query of the Salesman Parameter to use the Distributor parameter
3. Beware that everytime you change the first parameter the second will be refreshed, and this can be anoying sometimes.

Good Luck.